# Resample monthly data to weekly data in pyspark with group by

Tags: pyspark

I have the below data.  The qty is the total amount of product sold for each item/division pair in that month.  I would like to resample this data using pyspark so that I can get the weekly (starting on Monday) for each item/division pair.  If the month is not in the original table it can be assumed to be 0

```
+----+---------+-------+----------+
|item|division |qty    |month     |
+----+---------+-------+----------+
|250 |West     |12187.0|2023-05-01|
|250 |West     |12187.0|2023-06-01|
|250 |West     |12187.0|2023-07-01|
|250 |East     |7353.0 |2023-06-01|
|250 |East     |7353.0 |2023-07-01|
|250 |East     |8311.0 |2023-08-01|
+----+---------+-------+----------+
```

My output should look something like this

```
+------+----------+---------+---------+
| Item | Division |  Date   |   Qty   |
+------+----------+---------+---------+
|  250 | East     | 5/1/23  | 1660.35 |
|  250 | East     | 5/8/23  | 1660.35 |
|  250 | East     | 5/15/23 | 1660.35 |
|  250 | East     | 5/22/23 | 1660.35 |
|  250 | East     | 5/29/23 | 1691.98 |
|  250 | East     | 6/5/23  | 1715.70 |
|  250 | East     | 6/12/23 | 1715.70 |
|  250 | East     | 6/19/23 | 1715.70 |
|  250 | East     | 6/26/23 | 1761.69 |
|  250 | East     | 7/3/23  | 1876.68 |
|  250 | East     | 7/10/23 | 1876.68 |
|  250 | East     | 7/17/23 | 1876.68 |
|  250 | East     | 7/24/23 | 1876.68 |
|  250 | East     | 7/31/23 |  268.10 |
|  250 | West     | 5/1/23  | 2751.90 |
|  250 | West     | 5/8/23  | 2751.90 |
|  250 | West     | 5/15/23 | 2751.90 |
|  250 | West     | 5/22/23 | 2751.90 |
|  250 | West     | 5/29/23 | 2804.32 |
|  250 | West     | 6/5/23  | 2843.63 |
|  250 | West     | 6/12/23 | 2843.63 |
|  250 | West     | 6/19/23 | 2843.63 |
|  250 | West     | 6/26/23 | 2817.42 |
|  250 | West     | 7/3/23  | 2751.90 |
|  250 | West     | 7/10/23 | 2751.90 |
|  250 | West     | 7/17/23 | 2751.90 |
|  250 | West     | 7/24/23 | 2751.90 |
|  250 | West     | 7/31/23 |  393.13 |
+------+----------+---------+---------+
```